# PyQt4 How to send push button signal to another class in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I need your advice and help for my code.

I am making a GUI program. Basically the program does the followings:

1. Gets input from the user
2. When a certain button is pushed, the program retrieves all the input and saved them in the database
3. The program does computations.
4. Shows the output

Here is the simple version of the program, calculator program:
[image: simple GUI program, calculator]

As you can see in the figure, it takes 4 input from user, (1) any integer for var1, (2) any integer for var2, (3) operator (addition or subtraction) and (4) click button.

The GUI was designed using QtDesigner.

And here is my code:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from testgui import Ui_MainWindow

class ShowAndInput(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        #connect to the database
        self.connect_to_db()

        #create table in the database
        self.create_table()

        #add items to the comboBox
        self.add_items()

        #calculate button to start calculating, gives signal to the next class Calculate
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.calculate)

        #close button to close the window
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), quit)

        self.conn.close()

    def connect_to_db(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('testguidb.sqlite3')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Input (var1 INTEGER, var2 INTEGER)''')
        self.conn.commit()

    def add_items(self):
        lst = ['addition', 'subtraction']
        self.ui.comboBox.clear()
        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(lst)

    def calculate(self):
        calculate = Calculate(self)
        calculate.exec_()
```

So the purpose of the first class was to show the GUI and take input from the user. If user clicks the pushbutton named 'Calculate', it should connect to the new class named 'Calculate'.

Here is my code for the Calculate class:

```
class Calculate(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        #validator to validate that the input is integer or digit

        #connect to database
        self.connect_to_db()

        #get the input values and store them in the database
        self.get_the_values()

        #print the output
        PrintOutcome()

    def connect_to_db(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('testguidb.sqlite3')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def get_the_values(self):
        dicti = {}
        dicti['var1'] = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        dicti['var2'] = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        for key, val in sorted(dicti.items()):
            key = str(key)
            val = int(val)
            self.cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Input (?) VALUES (?)',(key,val))
            self.conn.commit()
```

And at the end of this class, it calls another class named 'PrintOutcome' to print out the result in the QTextBrowser. Here is the last piece of the code:

```
class PrintOutcome(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        #connect to database
        self.connect_to_db()

        #get the value of the combobox
        self.get_combox()       

        #print the output
        if self.operator == 'addition': self.print_add()
        elif self.operator == 'subtraction': self.print_sub()

    def connect_to_db(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('testguidb.sqlite3')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def get_combox(self):
        self.operator = str(self.ui.comboBox.currentText())

    def print_add(self):
        dicti={}
        for i in range(2):
            i = i + 1
            dicti['var{0}'.format(i)] = self.cur.execute('SELECT var{0} FROM Input'.format(i))
            dicti['var{0}'.format(i)] = int(self.cur.fetchone()[0])
            text = str(dicti['var{0}'.format(i)])
            self.ui.textBrowser.append(text)
        result = dicti['var1'] + dicti['var2']
        textsep = '-'*25+'(+)'      
        text = str(result)      
        self.ui.textBrowser.append(text)
        self.ui.textBrowser.append(text)

    def print_sub(self):
        dicti={}
        for i in range(2):
            i = i + 1
            dicti['var{0}'.format(i)] = self.cur.execute('SELECT var{0} FROM Input'.format(i))
            dicti['var{0}'.format(i)] = int(self.cur.fetchone()[0])
            text = str(dicti['var{0}'.format(i)])
            self.ui.textBrowser.append(text)
        result = dicti['var1'] + dicti['var2']
        textsep = '-'*25+'(-)'      
        text = str(result)      
        self.ui.textBrowser.append(text)
        self.ui.textBrowser.append(text)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = ShowAndInput()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I ran it, everything was fine. But when I pressed the calculate button, it returned an error message.
[image: everything is fine when I run it]

[image: Get an error message when I click the calculate button]

Here is the error message: RuntimeError: super-class **init**() of type Calculate was never called.

Any respond will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Regards,

Arnold

Comment: Why are you creating separate classes for each operation?  You don't actually want 3 separate windows, do you?  You could easily do this with a handful of functions all on the first class.

Comment: @Brendan Abel thanks for your question. In my actual program, the input will be much more than this simple version. So if I use functions instead of classess, then there will be a lot of functions inside the functions. Do you think it is better to have various functions inside a function rather than various functions inside a class? Once again, thanks for your question.